# How do I split HTML / XML with Regex for only siblings with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, xml

I have some text:

```
<p>I hope that this works!</p> <p>Now that this is in, let's see!</p><p>I hope that bold <strong>works too</strong>!</p>
<p>Will this works</p><ol><li>First item</li><li>Second item</li><li>Third item</li></ol>
```

I want to split it into:

```
<p>I hope that this works!</p>
```

and

```
<p>Now that this is in, let's see!</p><p>I hope that bold <strong>works too</strong>!</p>
```

and

```
<ol><li>First item</li><li>Second item</li><li>Third item</li></ol>
```

I don't want to split on any of the child elements, just the siblings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way to parse an X/HTML-alike string is by using the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)

```js
const str = `<p>I hope that this works!</p>
  <p>Now that this is in, let's see!</p>
  <p>I hope that bold <strong>works too</strong>!</p>
  <p>Will this works</p>
  <ol><li>First item</li><li>Second item</li><li>Third item</li></ol>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");

console.log(doc.body.children)
```

Or like this, to map the outerHTML as an Array of strings

```js
const str = `<p>I hope that this works!</p>
  <p>Now that this is in, let's see!</p>
  <p>I hope that bold <strong>works too</strong>!</p>
  <p>Will this works</p>
  <ol><li>First item</li><li>Second item</li><li>Third item</li></ol>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/html");
const children = doc.body.children;
const chStrArr = [...children].map(el => el.outerHTML);

console.log(chStrArr);
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser
- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Is `DOMParser` fast?

Comment: @Shamoon If you find browsers fast in interpreting and creating a [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), than yes. It's the first best thing you can use - not only for that specific task, but whenever you need to parse strings as actual Documents (which is by no means a RegExp job).